# Animated Android View with EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-activity, android-animation

For the app I'm working on, the signon screen (the main activity) has some animations. Several of the signon related controls (the EditText, an application banner image, the signon button, locked out link, etc) are wrapped into a LinearLayout that starts out centered in parent within a full screen RelativeLayout. When the user taps into the EditText, the animation fades out the banner image as the logon form translates to the top of the screen. When the user dismisses the keyboard the banner image fades in as the form slides back down to the center of the screen.

The two issues are as follows (the first one is the most important since I don't have a workaround for it right now):

1. When the user is typing into the EditText after it's been animated to the top  (it isn't actually animated to the top, the containing LinearLayout is) then you almost never see any text that is typed. It's random... sometimes the hint stays there and sometimes you might see a letter or two. When the keyboard is dismissed and the animation moves everything back to the start, the text is visible. Why?!
2. When the signon screen is put into the background and then resumed, Android appears to show some cached version of the screen where the controls are in their "focused" state but none of them work. Tapping on the screen where the controls would normally be (in the center) reveals the controls and starts the animation to move them to the top. This happens even if when the screen goes into the background, it's in it's regular state. I "fixed" this by setting a flag when the activity is paused and then checking if the flag is set in resume... if it is then I recreate the activity (by launching a new intent, not by calling recreate since I have to support an older API). It would be awesome if it just didn't show the cached version without me having to jump through these hoops.

Comment: What are you using to do the animations? It sounds like you have moved the visual location of your LinearLayout, but not the actual layout location. For example, you can use ObjectAnimator to move the position of a view, but if you don't modify the layout then you can see weird behavior like this. Can you add an animation listener, and in onAnimationEnd, make your ImageView GONE, so the LinearLayout is naturally at the top of your RelativeLayout? If you post your XML and code I can try an answer.

Comment: I'm using 2 animations started at the same time. One is an AlphaAnimation on the ImageView and the other is a TranslateAnimation on the LinearLayout. The alpha goes from 1 to 0 when the EditText gets focus and 0 to 1 when it loses focus. The translate goes from a y of 0 relative to self to a y of 0.1 relative to parent. It's easy enough to set the image to gone in the animation end but I think it would be much more difficult to set the position of the layout to where the animation stops it I think.

Comment: Well, you couldn't set it to 0.1 exactly, but you could probably get pretty close. For example, you probably have margin or padding to separate your image and text. If that margin is approximately equal to 0.1 of the parent, then just setting the image to gone would do the trick. Anyway, I think this is your issue: the TranslateAnimation is changing where you see the view, but other Android code is not realizing that the EditText has had its position translated.